# How to make a progress bar with my logo

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to have a loading bar for my website so it loads the data as soon as the page is opened. The problem is I dont know how to change the loading bar. I have a Logo in PNG that want to change its colour from one to other while the content is loading.  There are many progress bar but what about having an image instead. Here is example of a simple bar: http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#label

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Could you post up the code you've attempted?

Comment: Try clicking on the `view source` link below the demo box.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Well my code is just like the link I send. As I have no idea how to it would work with an image, I havent done anything with that. Just a simple progress bar.

Comment: @Xareyo I know, but it does not show how the interface of the bar is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Progressbar API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/#method-option):

Part of the documentation explains the main class names of the Progressbar Widget, which can be themed via CSS:

> - **ui-progressbar:**  The outer container of the progressbar. This element will additionally have a class of ui-progressbar-indeterminate for indeterminate progressbars.
> - **ui-progressbar-value:** The element that represents the filled portion of the progressbar.
> - **ui-progressbar-overlay:**  Overlay used to display an animation for indeterminate progressbars.

Therfore to add your own logo/image to the bar you want to extend one of these classes.

For example, to make the filled part of the progressbar have a background image define:

```
.ui-progressbar-value {
    background: url(http://i62.tinypic.com/2uy4mjs.png);
}
```

You can see my example at the below link:

http://jsfiddle.net/qCCzE/2/

Comment: Thanks, your answer and the example just gave me the idea to approach this custom loader.